# setting exif using libjpeg

Tags: c++, exif, libjpeg

I am using libjpeg to compress and write jpeg images. Is there any way that I can write  exif  data at the same time? I think libjpeg has a function to do this, but I am not sure what is the function name and how to use it. Is there any example on doing this?

Edit 1

I found a code such as follow, but I am not sure about the detail:

```
struct jpeg_compress_struct JpegStruct;
struct exifblock exif; 
jpeg_write_marker(&JpegStruct, 0xe1, (unsigned char *) &exif, exifsize );
```

Apperently, it write exif as a marker in jpeg which is the low level of doing this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no function in libjpeg that adds Exif data. libjpeg handles any JPEG image (compressing and decompressing). Exif data is added by digital cameras to JPEG and TIFF images.

Comment: @JimMerkel: Please see my amended question.

Comment: Ok, it looks like you can write Exif data then. Assume you have a Hex editor. With that and the Exif Spec, have a go at it.